# Error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '' token?

Tags: c++, debugging, operator-overloading

i keep getting this error and im not sure how to get ride of it. i am a beginner and was trying to build a code to practice operator overloading. first i had the errors say that there was unidentified reference to FeetInches(unsigned int= 0, int= 0). then i tried implementing the constructor and got that error

```
 #include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
using namespace std;
class FeetInches
{
private:
   unsigned int feet;
   int inches;
   void simplify();
public:
   FeetInches(unsigned int= 0, int= 0);
   FeetInches operator+(const FeetInches &);
   void display();
};

void FeetInches::simplify()
{
if (inches >=12)
   {
      feet+= (inches/12);
      inches = inches % 12;
   }// end of IF
else if (inches <0)
 {
  feet-=((abs(inches)/12)+1);
  inches = 12-(abs(inches)%12);
  }// end of elseif
}// end of simplify

FeetInches FeetInches::operator+(const FeetInches & right)
{
   FeetInches one (10,15);
   FeetInches ruler(5,3);
   FeetInches temp;
   temp=one+ruler;// temp one.operator +(ruler)
   temp.display();
}
 FeetInches::FeetInches(feet =0,inches=0)
 {

 }

void FeetInches::display()
{
    cout << "F: " << feet <<  " I:" <<  inches << endl;
}

int main()
{
   FeetInches aMeasure;
   aMeasure.display();


   return 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax should be

```
FeetInches(unsigned int feet = 0, int inches = 0);
```

for the declaration, and instead

```
FeetInches::FeetInches(unsigned int feet, int inches)
    : feet(feet), inches(inches)
{ }
```

in the definition.

The reasons are technical, not logical, and they depend on how C++ is implemented at lower levels.

Default value for arguments are for example provided by the **caller** of a function and therefore they must be specified in the **declaration** of the function because in C++ it's not guaranteed that the compiler will know the implementation of a function when compiling calls to it.

Answer (score 0):

that is obvious , you did'nt append the constructor body to your code , to do that you can write this :

```
class type_name{
   public : 
      type_name (...ARGS...){ ... }
};
```

or this

```
class type_name{
   public :
      type_name (...ARGS...);
};
type_name(... ARGS ...){ ...body.. }
```

so you need to append the body or the linker wont generate binaries , there you are what is happening behind  it :

1- then compiler is called to generated a .obj file for each { .c/.cpp/.cxx ... } you write .
 2- the linker is then called to create the final output , to do that he need to find reference  for each called function  in any of the .obj files., if you write a function declaration only and you don't call it the linker may give a warning only but if you call it he need to find it's code . because he need to replace the call with the code address . if there is no code he will give you a indefined refference error .

For each function code there is a header that tells about arrguments  nember an types to pass to this code . he you that to find the function body . you wrote in the declaration  "FeetInches(unsigned int= 0, int= 0);" that is the header , and you called the function later with those arguments then the linker need to find the code that corresponds to that header but he did'nt  find it because in the implementation you did'nt append the type 
( acctually it is more then that but that's what you need to know right now   the linker adds some extra arguments ...)
here you can find more about this topic http://faculty.cs.niu.edu/~mcmahon/CS241/Notes/compile.html
http://www.tenouk.com/ModuleW.html
Note : put default values only in the declaration (inside the class) and don't repeate them outside it , acctualy modern compilers don't accept what you wrote and assign a error ( at least when you use default copiling arguments in the command line ) , and when you put the body outside the class add the arguments types to make sure that the compiler will find it .